# What graphing library does GitHub use on its Graphs page?

Tags: javascript, github, graphing

What graphing library does GitHub use on its Graphs tab? When you navigate to https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/graphs/commit-activity the graphs are clean, beautiful, and responsive. If they are using an open source javascript library, I would love to use it as well! I have not been able to tell from a brief code inspection.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The new GitHub graphs are built with the amazing d3 library by @mbostock.

http://github.com/mbostock/d3

This was taken directly from https://github.com/blog/1093-introducing-the-new-github-graphs

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! An amazing library indeed.

Comment: Thanks. I was almost sure that but when I look source code which is minified, I can find anything related to d3 :) All code is put inside a "frameworks.js"